# jquery not selector is not woking on a active class

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

So i have 2 tabs (Tab1 and Tab2). One has a class of active and other doesn't have a class.
When i click on tab2 it should toggle between a 'row' class or a 'list' class based on what is it.

I am able to achieve it with based on my code below.

But when i click on Tab1 I dont want the same effect to take place because it has an active class to it.

I have the following code set up to do that. But that does not seem to work:

```
    $(document).on('click', '#view:not(.active)', toggleEvent);

    function toggleEvent() {
      $('.view-container').toggleClass('row').toggleClass('list');
    }
```

Here is the jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/RDewq/1/

Does :not only work with list elements?

Comment: Your CSS code is malformed, you have brackets in brackets, you don't need this here.

Comment: why the negative vote? Its a valid question, with examples of what I have tried along with the jsfiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting an event firing when a click occurs on the #view div since it does NOT have .active class:

```
$(document).on('click', '#view a:not(.active)', toggleEvent);
function toggleEvent(){
alert('test');
  $('.view-container').toggleClass('row').toggleClass('list');
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RDewq/2/

Comment: `$(document).on('click', '#view :not(.active)', toggleEvent);` will also work

Comment: I agree it does.  It seems as if it shouldn't though since a click on div#view fires an event and it does not have an .active class.